# Send attachment with email using WCF

Tags: silverlight, .net-3.5, wcf

We need to build an email functionality in our application and the application will be based on Silverlight. In this application user will be able to send the email with attachement. So for this purpose we have realized that we need to build and utilize WCF service which is not a problem. The place where I am stuck is that how can I attach the files and send it to outside world with email.

So please any guidence and article will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to integrate a [file uploader](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/) into your Silverlight application to place the files somewhere on your server.  You can then use standard WCF to invoke code you've placed on the server to piece together the email using .NET SMTP client components.